# Prototypes and Class/Constructor/Object Members

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am quite confused about the prototype chain and inheritance in JavaScript. The Date() object for example has the member methods/functions such as `Date.now()`. Why is it then when you create a new instance of the Date() object, and call the now() method, it throws an error? `new Date.now()`
But when calling a prototype method such as `getTime`, caling `new Date().getTime()` works but not `Date().getTime()` without creating a new instance. Why is that? I had an understanding that prototypes of objects become part of the original object?
For example:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
     this.firstname = firstName;
     this.lastname = lastName;
     this.getfirstName = () => {
              return this.firstName;
     }
}

Person.prototype.getlastName = () => {
      return this.lastName;
}
```

Doesn't the prototype method `getlastName` become a member method of `Person` and can be accessed without using the `new` keyword like how it must be used with getTime() for Date()?

Comment: `getLastName` is returning `this.lastName` which means it acts on the instance. Checkout http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/ it might clear some things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prototype` adds an instance method, meaning it gets attached to instances of the class. For your example, the function `getlastName` will only be called like so:

```
var p = new Person("first","last");
p.getlastName();
```

or

```
new Person("first","last").getlastName();
```

If you want `getlastName` to be attached to the class itself, you needn't use `Prototype` :

```
Person.getlastName = () => { return this.lastName }
```

In the case of the `Date` class, `now` is a static method (does not use `Prototype`) while `getTime` is an instance method (uses `Prototype`). You can see it in its documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Here's a reference to static and prototype methods: http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2009/04/09/object-oriented-javascript-tip-creating-static-methods-instance-methods/

Comment: I see. That clears things up a bit. Thank you very much. I come from a C++ background and it is totally confusing me. However just one more thing. When you say if I want getlastName() to be attached to the class itself and do `Person.getlastName = () => { return this.lastName }` would that be the same thing as having it defined in the constructor itself such as `getfirstName()`? And if I attach it like you suggested, can it be accessed after by just doing Person.getlatName() and it will return lastname?